# How do you effectively submit an opponent in UFC Undisputed 2010?

Tags: ufc-undisputed-2010

What are some effective methods for submitting opponents in UFC Undisputed 2010? How do the energy and stamina bar factor into submission attempts? How does charging (clicking and holding the right stick) compare with shining (rotating the right stick)?

Answer (score 1):

> The best way we found to guarantee a submission was to weaken your
>   opponent beforehand. With enough kicks to the ribs from standing, your
>   opponent will get rocked very easily. From there, you can do a
>   takedown, slap on a submission, and probably submit him because his
>   stamina is just that low. He can still get out if your shine is bad or
>   if your ratings are terrible, but in general, attempting a submission
>   on a fighter who is rocked is almost guaranteed to work.

^ Taken from [IGN AU](http://au.guides.ign.com/guides/22736/page_11.html)

[Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_6750223_submit-fighters-ufc-2010-undisputed.html) is an eHow i found on the topic that may be useful.